# NHibernate.Envers: Configuration by NHibernate core xml

Tags: c#, nhibernate

My goal is to configure NHibernate.Envers by a configuration file. As far as I understod the documentation, it should be easily possible by adding a property entry in the NHibernate Core xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <session-factory name="NHibernate.Test">
    ....
    <property name="nhibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix">_history</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But this leads to an Exception:

> The 'name' attribute is invalid - The value 'nhibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix' is invalid according to its datatype 'String' - The Enumeration constraint failed.

I do understand the exception, NHibernate core checks for valid content in the name attribute. How can I set a NHibernate.Envers property?

The same property works when I set it by code:

```
        cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.Configure("NHibernate.cfg.xml");

        // NHibernate.Envers Configuration
        cfg.SetProperty("nhibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix", "_history");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the documentation is wrong. You cannot put this in your NH Core configuration because NH Core will do schema validation on your xml (and is unaware of the envers properties).

I will update Envers docs shortly.

Comment: Hm, ok, no configuration by xml-file possible then, right? Don't worry, I'm going to put the configuration worthy options in my applications configuration and set the properties accordingly. Might be easier for the user anyway...